# Error using mat-checkbox inside an editable material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I've created an editable using Angular Material, when a row is in an editable state each cell will show an input field depending on what data type is being displayed, e.g. if the cell is a string it will have an input field of type 'text'.

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label> {{column}} </mat-label>
   <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="element[column]"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

This works fine when using either text or number but I want to have a boolean checkbox as well, but when I try to use `mat-checkbox` instead of input I get an error 'mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.'. Even though I'm using `ngModel` the same as I am with text and numbers.

```html
<div *ngIf="column === 'checkType'>
   <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element[column]"></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can't use `mat-checkbox` inside of a `mat-form-field` (not supported): see https://github.com/angular/components/issues/7891

So when you use `mat-checkbox`, don't nest it inside a `mat-form-field`. You can give it a `formControlName` or `[(ngModel)]` directly, without the mat-form-field.

```html
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myVariable">
```